# Print numeric and non-numeric in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

how to print numbers and non-numbers in array?

> Create a method in this class that takes a List of strings as the only
>   argument. Each string in this list will be a single word containing
>   either alphabets a through z or digits 0 through 9 (for example,
>   “abcd”, “Pune”, “623”, “Mumbai”, “10”, etc.
>
> 3. The method should print on standard output 2 numbers:
>
>    a. How many strings in the input array are numbers
>
>    b. How many strings in the input array are non-numeric.

Comment: I'm searching a correct answer, but you should add "Java" tag to your question to get more help. ;)

Comment: Might this be relevant? [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer: count them first. :-)

Adding a bit more depth: declare two variables for the counts. Remember to initialize to 0. Iterate over the list. For each string add 1 to either one or the other counter. Print both counters at the end.

For determining whether a string is numeric or alphabetic: It depends on the validation required. For production code I would check whether *all* the characters are numeric or *all* alphabetic. If this is not a requirement, you may get away with just looking at the first char of the string. In any case the methods `Character.isLetter` and `Character.isDigit` are helpful.

Or the advanced option: use a stream operation. I’d use the two-arg `<T,D,A> Collectors.partitioningBy​(Predicate<? super T>, Collector<? super T,A,D>)` and an auxiliary method for determining whether a string is numeric or not for the predicate.

I suggest that you make your own attempt first. Once you’ve completed it, you may want to compare your solution with the one by kiliz in the other answer. If you get stuck underway, please ask a new question. We’re here to help. And please read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before doing that.

**Documentation links**

- [`Character.isLetter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char))
- [`Character.isDigit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))
- [Two-arg `Collectors.partitioningBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.stream.Collector))

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
void method(String[] strings)
{
 int numeric = 0, non_numeric = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
 {
  try
  {
   Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
   numeric ++;
  }
  catch(NumberFormatException e)
  {
   non_numeric ++;
  }
 }
 print(numeric);
 print(non_numeric);
}
```

**EDIT :** To understand the code :

We have to found two values (number of numeric and number of non-numeric values in the array), so we initialize two ints that will contains these values.

We look each values of the array, and try to convert it into an int with `parseInt`.
There are several possible cases, at least one of them can raise an error (take a look at [Integer.parseInt documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))), so we use the `try` statement :

- conversion work → add 1 to numeric counter
- conversion doesn't work → `parseInt` raises a NumberFormatException that we catch with the `catch` statement → add 1 to non-numeric counter

Then we print both values in the standard output.

Comment: noted @OleV.V. , I'll be more carefull next time.

Comment: I've added an EDIT to explain code and ideas behind it, so else if it really was homework, maybe the student will learn something...

Comment: In any case it’s a good explanation, thanks.